# Show different Plymouth screen on boot vs. shutdown

Tags: boot, shutdown, startup, plymouth

I am working on a project which has a custom Plymouth boot screen. I wanted to make the progress bar out of text (so the text slides from grey to white/color), but then it would show "nekOS 7 is starting up" on the shutdown screen. Especially in those random instances where it takes a long time to shut down, that would probably confuse the end-user.

So, what I am wondering is if there is a relatively easy way (or any way at all, as treacherous as it may be, hopefully aside from redoing code in the Plymouth splash screen) to have a separate boot screen for shutdown compared to the one at startup?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the script for your custom theme use Plymouth.GetMode() and compare against "boot", "shutdown", "suspend" or "resume".

I.e

```
if (Plymouth.GetMode () == "suspend")
{
     ShowSuspendBackground();
}
```

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/Scripts/